# Magento 2.4.4 - Salesrule Model Validator::process() was changed from 2.4.3 to 2.4.4

Tags: magento2.4

Facing an issue on SalesRule Validator Process() (i.e)

```
vendor\magento\module-sales-rule\Model\Validator.php
    public function process(AbstractItem $item, Rule $rule)
    {
        $itemPrice = $this->getItemPrice($item);
        if ($itemPrice < 0) {
            return $this;
        }
        $appliedRuleIds = $this->rulesApplier->applyRules(
            $item,
            [$rule],
            $this->_skipActionsValidation,
            $this->getCouponCode()
        );
        $this->rulesApplier->setAppliedRuleIds($item, $appliedRuleIds);
        return $this;
    }
```

Custom Code:
//calling vendor\magento\module-sales-rule\Model\Validator::process()

$items =  $this->cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();

/** @var Item $item */
foreach ($items as $key => $item) {
$this->salesRuleValidator->process($item, $this->salesRuleValidator->_getRules($item->getAddress()))

}

I am not able to set the Rule object on my custom code.. Any one can help for this modifications?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we found a solution this issue. The newer version of 2.4.4 rule is mandatory   object and applied custom discount percentage and amount properly.

We have solved the rule based discount issue via zero discount for subtotal.

We needed to be better approach...